# Sobre preparação do servidor apache tomcat no visual studio code

Tags: tomcat, visual-studio-code, terminal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Baixei os arquivos binários do apache-tomcat, extrai em uma pasta aberta e adicionei no visual studio code. Mas na hora de startar o servidor, deu esse erro que não dá nem para ler direito, como mostra ali no terminal. Alguém sabe qual a solução para este problema ?

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro no console é pq não existe uma variável de ambiente apontando pro tomcat.

Se vc já tem alguma aplicação pra rodar nele, tenta seguir isso aqui:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tomcat-jetty